# Вылетает ошибка в свойстве «SelectedFolder.IsFolder» компонента «ShellListView»

Tags: delphi, компоненты

Доброе время суток.

Для вывода содержимого директорий использую компонент *ShellListView*. 
Для реакции программы только на выделенные файлы использую код:

```
  procedure TForm1.ShellListViewClick(Sender: TObject);  
  begin  
     if not(ShellListView.SelectedFolder.IsFolder) then  
     begin  
       {перенос наименования выделенного файла в StrinGrid}  
     end;  
  end;
```

Код отрабатывет нормально. 
Но если в этом компоненте случайно нажать лев. кнопку мышки на пустую область, выскакивает:

*«Project Project1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 0046FDCF in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 0000000C'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.»*

Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если выделения нет, то SelectedFolder будет nil. Правильно так:

```
if (ShellListView.SelectedFolder<>nil)
  and not(ShellListView.SelectedFolder.IsFolder) then
begin
  {перенос наименования выделенного файла в StrinGrid}  
end;
```

Comment: Еще раз спасибо :-)